# cannot fetch data from api although it connect

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I tried to connect backend laravel and frontend angularjs using api and ajax $http method. The api is connected but the data cannot view in ng-repeat method.I dont know what was the mistake.I hope anyone can help to figure it. Thanks in advance.

Hello.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Laravel + Angularjs</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Todoctrl">
        <li ng-repeat="x in todos">
            {{ x.name }}
        </li>
    </div>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp',[])
    .controller('Todoctrl',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
        var onStatsComplete = function(response){
            $scope.todos = response.data;
        }
        $http.get("api/todos").then(onStatsComplete);
    }

]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

api.php

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
Route::get('/todos','HomeController@todos');
```

HomeController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function todos(){
        $data = [ 
        "name" => "sithi",
        "mobile" => "0108817531",
        "email"  =>  "check",
        "status" => 0
    ];

        return response()->json($data)->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials','true')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET,POST,OPTIONS')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type');
    }
}
```

Comment: please post the output of `console.log(data.response);` in `onStatsComplete` function

Comment: @AhmedNourJamalEl-Din  yes i tried as u mention. it display the data inside api in the console but template never show.Actually the listing shows in 5 line follow the data row but data never shown. Actually in template it listing the number of data instead of displaying it.

Comment: so is `$data` array or one object? I mean can you `ng-repeat` on it or no?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked what `response.data` contains? A typical Laravel api response using resource collections would put the array under its own data key, which makes `response.data.data` the final key required to access the values from your JS in those situations.